# Images in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image, crystal-reports, dataset

I am working on Windows Forms Projects.

I am creating a report for customers.
The report data is pulled from a "CustomerDetails" table.

A field in the table is called "CustPhotoName", this holds a string which relates to an image file.

I Currently have a report set up which runs for a single customer by passing in a customer ID. Then using the passed in ID to populate a Dataset with an ImageRow and then a sub report with the image from the dataset.

I am wanting to set up this report where I can pass in an array of customer IDs and produce the reports (1 page per customer with image (if CustPhotoName has value))

Please can someone let me know how is the best way to do this for the multiple customers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CustomerID parameter to the report.  Type Number.  Set it to allow multiple values.  In the report's record-selection formula, add the following:

AND {table.customer_id} IN {?CustomerID}

You probably want to group the report by {CustomerID} as well.  In the group's footer, select Section Expert and check New Page After.  This way each customer will start on a new page.

Comment: I can get 1 customer per page, no problem. It's the customer photo that's causing headaches. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe what is happening?  What type of image (e.g JPG) are you storing?